# JQuery removes events after dom load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I have an issue with jquery.

The scenario is this:

I trigger different custom events using Jquery's event delegation like this:

```
$(document).trigger("myCustomEvent");
```

And listen to them like so:

```
$(document).on("myCustomEvent",function(e){
    //Triggered
});
```

The thing is that I load pages dynamically using AJAX, which might have scripts.

In cases where the loaded page includes Jquery, the inclusion breaks the binding of the events.

Is there any way to solve this?? Doesn't jquery validates if it is loaded?

I don't have control over the loaded pages, because they are external

Here is a fiddle replicating this behavior (http://jsfiddle.net/97eca61w/15/) where the triggered event should appear twice..

```js
$(document).on("myCustomEvent",null,function(e){
   //debugger;
    $("#log").append("<p>Custom event triggered</p>");
  });

$(document).ready(function(e){
  
  //debugger;
  
  $("#contentDiv").html("<scr" + "ipt src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' ></scr" + "ipt><scr" + "ipt>$(document).ready(function(e){alert('ready')})</scri" + "pt>");
  
  console.log($._data($(document)[0],"events"));
  
  $(document).trigger("myCustomEvent");
  
  setTimeout(function(){
   debugger;
    $(document).trigger("myCustomEvent");
    console.log($._data($(document)[0],"events"));
  },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="contentDiv">
  </div>
  <div id="log">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you reload jQuery, it will re-install itself. That will blow away all the data structures established by the previous installation.

Comment: Ok great, that's what I thought! But is there any way around this?? Doesn't jquery validate if it's loaded?

Comment: No it doesn't. It assumes that if it's being asked to run again that that's for some good reason. Maybe you could load your pages into an `<iframe>` or something.

Comment: Ok thanks! That's what I was going to do if I had no workaround